# ActionBarSherlock as inner class

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, inner-classes

I'm able to extend SherlockActivity in an inner class and use it in outer class.

BUT I couldnt use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("test")` in outer class

I tried to create new class in my outer class onCreate but still couldnt set title!

2.issue :  `MyActionbar myactionbar = new MyActionbar ()` doesnt work in android 2.3

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
MyActionbar myactionbar = new MyActionbar ();

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// ...
}

public class MyActionbar extends SherlockActivity  {

         @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("test");
}
}
```